# how do i customize font faces and sizes in neotree buffer

Tags: fonts, neotree

I am trying to find a good folder view package to work alongside projectile and magit, I tried treemacs for a while and did not find it to my liking,  I am now trying neotree.  Neotree seems to be good enough for me.  My only peeve is that i cant seem to find any documentation on how fonts can be customized in the tree view.

To begin with, it loaded with icons as i opened it up in graphical mode, i did not like that, i preferred a minimalistic look and went for a simple arrow theme which works for me.  i want to be able to do just two more things before i can finally say i have found the package that works for me

1. need to be able to make the font more compact so that i can fit more content as i will be working with multiple projects with nested folders.  I want to be able to use a font size on the tree thats considerably smaller than the editor font
2. need to be able to switch to a proportional as i feel that will be more compact and better suited for a file listing.

Anything that you can point me to would be great.  I am ok to mess around with elisp code in configuration.

Comment: This question is all over the place. Please post a specific question. This could be such a question: *"How can I find documentation on how fonts can be customized in the tree view?"* (once you've specified what you mean by "the tree view").